# Регулярные выражения в notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно найти и удалить все элементы **object** с атрибутом `data=\"http://site.ru/uppod/uppod.swf\"`.

Вот пример с этим элементом:

```
<object id=\"videoplayer630\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"http://site.ru/uppod/uppod.swf\" width=\"540\" height=\"440\">
   <param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#ffffff\" /><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\" />
   <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://site.ru/uppod/uppod.swf\" />
   <param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"st=http://site.ru/uppod/video120-1233.txt&amp;pl=http://site.ru/uppod/playlist_video120-630-316.txt\" />
</object>
```

Решил это сделать с помощью поиска и замены в Notepad++, но никак не выходит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Опять кто-то пытается парсить XML регулярными выражениями. Это превращается в местный мем. Люди одумайтесь.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @igumnov человеку нужно один раз в блокноте прогнать html-документ. Это действительно лучший вариант в этой ситуации.

Comment: @Etki Каждый раз когда кто-то парсит регулярным выражением html/xml разметку умирает один единорог.

Comment: @igumnov вы предлагаете писать одноразовый скрипт для однократного прохождения по одному файлу? Ой вей. Это вообще ни разу не парсинг.

Comment: @Etki Да почему одноразовый, может завтра ему потребуется что-то еще делать с этими объектами, а в скрипте хоть модель останется на всякий случай.

Comment: Потому что пользователь прямо пишет, что ему нужно не вытягивать информацию, а удалить несколько тегов. Слепо следовать заветам - это карго-культ; да, приятно написать работающий скрипт, только вот затраты по времени могут различаться в десятки раз.

Comment: Все равно это переход на темную сторону /thread

Comment: Какой-то странный xml. Почему кавычки экранированные?

Comment: Это кусок из дампа БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<object[^>]*data=\\"http:\/\/site\.ru\/uppod\/uppod\.swf\\".+?<\/object>\s*\n*
```

Проверил - работает и чужие тэги не трогает.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я упустил [^>] =). В итоге notepad съел это: <object[^>]*data=\\"http://site.ru/uppod/uppod.swf\\"+?[^>]+>(.*?)<\/object>

Answer (score 0):

```
<object.*?data=\\"http://site.ru/uppod/uppod.swf\\".*?</object>
```